# How to add github sponsor button to readme

Tags: github

I have github sponsorship enabled through my github repo.

I'm wanting to add a 'sponsor' button into the actual readme.md as well as another website.

Is there some what to add the sponsor button to these type of locations?

Answer (score 6):

shields.io has support for GitHub Sponsors badge. Go to https://shields.io/category/funding to create one.

For example:

```
![GitHub Sponsor](https://img.shields.io/github/sponsors/<username>?label=Sponsor&logo=GitHub)
```

Replace `<username>` with your GitHub username.

would display a badge

[image]

If you want to make it clickable:

```
[![](https://img.shields.io/static/v1?label=Sponsor&message=%E2%9D%A4&logo=GitHub&color=%23fe8e86)](https://github.com/sponsors/<username>)
```

Replace `<username>` with your GitHub username.

would display a badge

[image]

Comment: Why _wouldn't_ you want to make it clickable? ;-)

Answer (score 0):

You can use a link or an image like described [here](https://github.community/t/how-to-embed-a-github-sponsors-button-in-readme/137494/6).

A link could look like this (with a heart emoji):

```
[:heart: Sponsor](https://github.com/sponsors/yourGitHubUserName)
```

An image could be uploaded to the repository or to the user content site (can be done by selecting/dragging a file a file into a text area that is rendered (e.g. files, issues, pull requests, discussions, wikis, ...):

```
[![Github Sponsorship](img/github_sponsor_btn.svg)](https://github.com/sponsors/yourGitHubUserName)
```